# Whenever I try to add import {TabViewModule} from 'primeng/tabview'; or paginator module, compilation failed

Tags: angular, primeng

Whenever I try to add import {TabViewModule} from 'primeng/tabview'; or paginator module, compilation failed with error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires 6 type argument(s).

> Angular CLI: 12.2.18
> Node: 14.17.6
> Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
> @angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.18
> @angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.18
> @angular-devkit/core            12.2.18
> @angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.18
> @angular/cli                    12.2.18
> @schematics/angular             12.2.18
> rxjs                            6.6.7
> typescript                      4.3.5

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: Can you please attach to your question the content of your `tsconfig` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use PrimeNG v14 with Angular v12. This is not going to work because PrimeNG release cycle is [aligned](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-long-term-support/) with Angular, which means the installed PrimeNG version should match the Angular version in the major part.

You need to either downgrade PrimeNG:

```bash
$ npm install primeng@12
```

or upgrade Angular:

```bash
$ ng update
```